# How to examine a jar file when the JDK is not installed

Tags: java, jar

I have a docker container which runs a jar file.  Normally, it needs the JRE but not the JDK, so the JDK is not installed in the container.

During development, I sometimes want to examine the jar file that is inside the container, usually to do something like

```
jar tf Some.jar | grep SomeClassThatShouldBeThere
```

or possibly run `java` to see the method signatures on a class.

Is there a simpler way to do this than installing the JDK in the container or copying the files out of the container?  I am hoping for an answer like

```
java oracle.java.internal.Jar <args>
```

possibly with a class path element.

Since this is for one-off debugging, I do not mind accessing a private API that might change in the next release.

My JRE version is

```
# java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Debian-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Debian-1, mixed mode)
```

The OS is

```
# uname -a
Linux c5891bfce794 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Jun 6 16:55:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Why not just use a decomplier?

Comment: I am trying to do this inside the container.  Is there a decompiler included in the JRE?

Comment: Every .jar file is actually a zip file.  Any unzip tool will work on it.  (The [JarFile class actually extends ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarFile.html)).